# Placing a textview correctly within a layout

Tags: android, android-layout, view

I have a custom dialog box which is a series of buttons, pickers and viewswitchers. I'm trying to put a textview that displays text above the setDate and setTime buttons. At the moment it displays the textview on top of the buttons.

How can i display the textview above the time and date buttons? Thanks.

[image]

>

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 

<RelativeLayout 
>     
>     android:padding="5dip" 
>     android:fitsSystemWindows="true" 
>     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
>     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
>     android:id="@+id/DateTimePicker" 
>     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
>     
>     
>     
>     <LinearLayout 
>         
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
>         android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
>         android:id="@+id/linearlayoutdatepickermessage" 
>         android:layout_marginTop="5dip"> 
>     
>     
>     <TextView
>         android:id="@+id/textviewdatetimepickermessage"
>         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>         android:layout_gravity="center"
>         
>          />
>     
>     </LinearLayout>
>     
>     <LinearLayout 
>         
>         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
>         android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
>         android:id="@+id/ViewSwitchButtons" 
>         android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"> 
>         
>         
>         
>         <Button 
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
>             android:layout_width="0dip" 
>             android:id="@+id/SwitchToDate" 
>             android:text="Set date" 
>             android:enabled="false" 
>             android:layout_weight="1"/>
>         
>         <Button 
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
>             android:layout_width="0dip" 
>             android:id="@+id/SwitchToTime" 
>             android:text="Set time" 
>             android:layout_weight="1"/>
>         
>         </LinearLayout> 
>         
>         <ViewSwitcher 
>             android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
>             android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
>             android:id="@+id/DateTimePickerVS" 
>             android:layout_below="@+id/ViewSwitchButtons" 
>             android:outAnimation="@android:anim/fade_out" 
>             android:inAnimation="@android:anim/fade_in"> 
>             
>             
>                 
>                 <LinearLayout 
>                     android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
>                     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
>                     android:id="@+id/TimeLayout" 
>                     android:fillViewport="true"> 
>                     
>                     <TimePicker 
>                         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
>                         android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
>                         android:id="@+id/TimePicker" 
>                         android:layout_marginRight="5dip" 
>                         android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"/>
>                     
>                     </LinearLayout> 
>                     
>                 <LinearLayout android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
>                 android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
>                 android:id="@+id/DateLayout" 
>                 android:fillViewport="true"> 
>                 
>                 <DatePicker 
>                     android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
>                     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
>                     android:id="@+id/DatePicker" 
>                     android:layout_marginRight="5dip" 
>                     android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"/>
>                 
>                 </LinearLayout> 
>                     
>                     </ViewSwitcher> 
>                     
>                     <LinearLayout 
>                         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
>                         android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
>                         android:id="@+id/ControlButtons" 
>                         android:layout_below="@+id/DateTimePicker" 
>                         android:paddingTop="185dip"> 
>                         
>                         <Button 
>                             android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
>                             android:layout_width="0dip" 
>                             android:id="@+id/SetDateTime" 
>                             android:text="@android:string/ok" 
>                             android:layout_weight="1"/> 
>                             
>                             <Button 
>                                 android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
>                                 android:layout_width="0dip" 
>                                 android:id="@+id/ResetDateTime" 
>                                 android:text="Reset" 
>                                 android:layout_weight="1"/>
>                             
>                         <!--     <Button 
>                                 android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
>                                 android:layout_width="0dip" 
>                                 android:id="@+id/CancelDialog" 
>                                 android:text="@android:string/cancel" 
>                                 android:layout_weight="1"/>  -->
>                                 
>                                 </LinearLayout> 
>                                 
>                                 </RelativeLayout>
```

[edit1]
[image]

[edit2]
[image]

[edit3]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout 

        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:orientation="vertical"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"> 



    <LinearLayout 

        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:id="@+id/linearlayoutdatepickermessage" 
        android:layout_marginTop="5dip"> 


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textviewdatetimepickermessage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"

         />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 

        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:id="@+id/ViewSwitchButtons" 
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
       > 



        <Button 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_width="0dip" 
            android:id="@+id/SwitchToDate" 
            android:text="Set date" 

            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        <Button 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_width="0dip" 
            android:id="@+id/SwitchToTime"
            android:enabled="false" 
            android:text="Set time" 
            android:layout_weight="1"/>

        </LinearLayout> 

        <ViewSwitcher 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:id="@+id/DateTimePickerVS" 

            android:outAnimation="@android:anim/fade_out" 
            android:inAnimation="@android:anim/fade_in"> 



                <LinearLayout 
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                    android:id="@+id/TimeLayout" 
                    android:fillViewport="true"> 

                    <TimePicker 
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                        android:id="@+id/TimePicker" 
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dip" 
                        android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"/>

                    </LinearLayout> 

                <LinearLayout android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:id="@+id/DateLayout" 
                android:fillViewport="true"> 

                <DatePicker 
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                    android:id="@+id/DatePicker" 
                    android:layout_marginRight="5dip" 
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"/>

                </LinearLayout> 

                    </ViewSwitcher> 

                    <LinearLayout 
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                        android:id="@+id/ControlButtons" 

                        android:paddingTop="185dip"> 

                        <Button 
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                            android:layout_width="0dip" 
                            android:id="@+id/SetDateTime" 
                            android:text="@android:string/ok" 
                            android:layout_weight="1"/> 

                            <Button 
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                                android:layout_width="0dip" 
                                android:id="@+id/ResetDateTime" 
                                android:text="Reset" 
                                android:layout_weight="1"/>

                        <!--     <Button 
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                                android:layout_width="0dip" 
                                android:id="@+id/CancelDialog" 
                                android:text="@android:string/cancel" 
                                android:layout_weight="1"/>  -->

                                </LinearLayout> 

                                </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: try to use padding in xml, its useful to place your textview or buttons in layouts successfully.

Answer (score 1):

On your `ViewSwitchButtons` LinearLayout, put this:

```
android:layout_below="@+id/linearlayoutdatepickermessage"
```

Okay, your Layout consists of:

1. LinearLayout1
2. ViewSwitcher
3. LinearLayout2
4. LinearLayout3

If you want to use RelativeLayout, you should add:

1. `android:layout_below="ID_LinearLayout1"` to ViewSwitcher
2. `android:layout_below="ID_ViewSwitcher"` to LinearLayout2
3. `android:layout_below="ID_LinearLayout2"` to LinearLayout3

Or **another alternative** is to change your `RelativeLayout` parent to `LinearLayout` with `android:orientation="vertical"`

Comment: Thanks that has done it. However the minus buttons are covered by the reset and ok buttons now. i've edited the question to show a screen-shot

Comment: You've given the wrong name on your LinearLayout and ViewSwitcher. On your LinearLayout put `android:layout_below="@+id/linearlayoutdatepickermessage"` and on your ViewSwitcher put `android:layout_below="YOUR_CORRECTED_ID_OF_LinearLayout"`

Comment: The point is: By default, View in RelativeLayout are AlignParentLeft and AlignParentTop. If your layout flow is Top to Bottom, consider using LinearLayout with orientation="vertical" as the parent.

Comment: I'm not sure if i've done this correctly but there is alot of space now between the pickers and the ok button. In the last LL it used to reference android:layout_below="@+id/DateTimePicker, so i changed it to android:layout_below="@+id/DateTimePickerVS. Is that what you meant?

Comment: Ok i've gone with the linerlayout with vertical orientation but it still looks like the screen-shot in edit2. the code i have now is edit3. i just need to remove the space between the bottom buttons and the picker. why is there space there when we are using linearlayout vertically?

Comment: Remove `paddingTop` in your `LinearLayout3`.

Answer (score 0):

in `RelativeLayout` , the default paramter of positioning a View is `alignParentTop = "true"`, so in your code , you didn't specify where to put the `Layout` of your `Buttons` ( set date/set time)  , so it will be placed on the top ( with the layout of `TextView` msg ) . so to put your Buttons below your textView modify your xml layout like this :

```
<LinearLayout         
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/ViewSwitchButtons" 
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearlayoutdatepickermessage" <!--this will put your buttons below the textView-->
>
```